# What are grammar checker tools that can be used when designing a new language?

Tags: language-design, grammar, recommendation

When designing a programming language, before even writing the compiler's code, what are existing tools allowing to write a grammar, which can then check it for ambiguities and test it with sample inputs ?

For example there is Antlr CLI: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md, any other tools that can be used early in the design process ?

Comment: Welcome to PLDI! This is pretty opinion based currently, since what's best will depend heavily on what language you're using, what sort of language you're making, and what your priorities are (performance, helpful error messages, etc.). Rephrasing it to be more about the reasons you'd pick one over another will help you to get more objective answers.

Comment: Formal language theory concerns itself with ambiguities, but if you're writing a real programming language, you'll usually just cherrypick the "more intuitive" parse in that case. You deal with ambiguity by just deciding which one looks better.

Comment: Relevant meta quesiton about recommendations - https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/should-we-allow-questions-asking-to-find-or-recommend-off-site-resources/262#262

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a prototyping approach than a "checking" approach, but in the past, I have relied on LR parser generators which take a grammar-like input specification, check it for LR validity, and generate a parser for the specification.

Specifically, in Rust, I have made use of the [LALRPOP](https://lalrpop.github.io/lalrpop/) tool for building parsers while I am in the "ideation" phase, and LALRPOP can produce helpful errors for a number of LR parsing ambiguities and issues.

Notably, I am pretty sure that LR parser generators tend to be somewhat strict, and may prevent you from expressing an otherwise valid or unambiguous production in your grammar, so it may not be suitable for all grammars or all levels of implementation.